# Why Vagrant fails after OS upgrade?

Tags: ruby, vagrant, gem

Multiple packages upgraded like gem, ruby and its plugins. Now when I run `vagrant up` I get:

```
Vagrant failed to initialize at a very early stage:

The plugins failed to initialize correctly. This may be due to manual
modifications made within the Vagrant home directory. Vagrant can
attempt to automatically correct this issue by running:

  vagrant plugin repair

If Vagrant was recently updated, this error may be due to incompatible
versions of dependencies. To fix this problem please remove and re-install
all plugins. Vagrant can attempt to do this automatically by running:

  vagrant plugin expunge --reinstall

Or you may want to try updating the installed plugins to their latest
versions:

  vagrant plugin update

Error message given during initialization: Unable to resolve dependency: 'fog-libvirt (>= 0.3.0)' requires 'ruby-libvirt (>= 0.7.0)'
```

I even removed the whole `vagrant` by `sudo apt-get remove --purge vagrant` but after fresh installation error keeps showing.

I tried to reinstall `sudo gem install ruby-libvirt` but nothing happened.

Is there something that I can try on `Ubuntu` to solve this problem and make `vagrant` up & running?

---

**EDIT-1:**

`vagrant plugin repair` displays:

```
Repairing currently installed plugins. This may take a few minutes...
Failed to automatically repair installed Vagrant plugins. To fix this
problem remove all user installed plugins and reinstall. Vagrant can
do this for you automatically by running the following command:

  vagrant plugin expunge --reinstall

Failure message received during repair:

Unable to resolve dependency: user requested 'vagrant-libvirt (> 0)
```

Then using `vagrant plugin expunge --reinstall`:

```
This command permanently deletes all currently installed user plugins. It
should only be used when a repair command is unable to properly fix the
system.

Continue? [N]: Y

All user installed plugins have been removed from this Vagrant environment!

Vagrant will now attempt to reinstall user plugins that were removed.
```

Answer (score 2):

I removed `ruby` & `gems` and also the vagrant directory `~/.vagrant.d` and reinstalled `vagrant`, `ruby` and `gems`. Now everything is up & running. It seems that error was related to `ruby` and `gems`.

Answer (score 0):

try the second option instead:

```
vagrant plugin update
```

I got this:

```
Updating installed plugins...
Updated 'vagrant-vbguest' to version '0.31.0'!
```

and everthing worked just fine